# mrss(Media RSS) feed for drupal 6

Tags: media

Is there a MRSS module for drupal 6? I have been asked to create a mrss feed of a site video content. This will enable AOL to access all the videos of the site via mrss. Will I have to create a custom module to achieve this?

Comment: there is no mrss for drupal 6.

Answer (score 0):

MRSS is just an XML.

There are many Views plugins to export data as XML. Specifically for MRSS, there is [Views RSS](https://drupal.org/project/views_rss_media). Or you can simply use template files to output data with proper tags.

It should be possible to use [Feeds XPath Parser](https://drupal.org/project/feeds_xpathparser) module to import MRSS, too.

The [Views RSS](https://drupal.org/project/views_rss_media) module is only for Drupal 7 and 8.